# Django: How to build a custom form widget?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am having a difficult time finding documentation on how to write a custom widget.

My questions are:

- If I build a custom widget, can it be used equivalently for the admin interface or for normal forms?
- If I want to allow the user to edit a list of items, what widget should I subclass? What methods of the widget do I need to override/implement?
- What widget method is responsible for going from the user's input back to the data model?

Thanks.

Comment: this certainly is helpfull http://tothinkornottothink.com/post/10815277049/django-forms-i-custom-fields-and-widgets-in-detail

Answer (score 56):

You're right in that Django doesn't supply documentation on this specific topic. I advise you to look at the builtin widgets in [`django.forms.widgets`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py) (I'll reference classes from that module below).

> If I build a custom widget, can it be used equivalently for the admin interface or for normal forms?

Admin overrides some widgets (see [`django.contrib.admin.options.FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py)). You can probably subclass `ModelAdmin` and change the `formfield_overrides` attribute, but I have never done anything with `ModelAdmin` so I can't help here...

> If I want to allow the user to edit a list of items, what widget should I subclass? What methods of the widget do I need to override/implement?

Your widget probably doesn't have anything in common with the default widgets (with `Select` if any?!). Subclass from `Widget` and if you find any common pattern with builtins, you can still change it later.

Implement the following methods:

- `render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None)`

  Check out `Input.render` for a simple example. It also supports user-defined attributes that are included in the HTML. You may also want to add "id" attributes, see `MultipleHiddenInput.render` on how to do that. Don't forget to use `mark_safe` when outputting HTML directly. If you have a rather complex widget you can use template rendering ([example](http://google.de/codesearch/p?hl=en#NVX-X1E4a8M/website/apps/cms/admin/widgets.py)).
- `_has_changed(self, initial, data)`

  Optional. Used in admin to log messages about what was changed.

> What widget method is responsible for going from the user's input back to the data model?

That has nothing to do with the widget - Django can't know what widget was used in an earlier request. It can only use the form (POST) data sent from the form. Therefore, the field method `Field.to_python` is used to convert input to the Python data type (may raise `ValidationError` if the input is invalid).

Comment: Ok, good to know. Is there a way that I can set `field.to_python` externally, or does overriding it require a custom field?

Comment: @Rosarch: Check the source of `django.forms.forms.BoundField.as_widget`, there's the call to `render`: The `name` parameter is the HTML name to be used for the form element, and `value` is the value that's bound to it (probably `None` for unbound field, dunno). `attrs` is a dictionary of additional attributes that should be included in the HTML element but that's not the attributes you define in the constructor (like `text = forms.TextArea(..., attrs = {...})` - I couldn't find a place where the `attrs` parameter is really used.

Comment: @Rosarch: Seems like my previous comment is gone... Concerning `to_python`, of course you cannot overwrite overwrite the builtin `Field.to_python` because that might break other fields, so you must subclass `Field`. In general I'd recommend you to just search the source code in this case - as long as documentation is missing.

Comment: @AndiDog -- in fact widgets do convert POST data, via the `value_from_datadict` method -- it's sort of the inverse of the widget's `render` method. This method is presumably what the Django docs on widgets are referring to when it says "The widget handles the rendering of the HTML, and the extraction of data from a GET/POST dictionary that corresponds to the widget."

Answer (score 25):

#### Django <1.11

Additionally to the other answers, this is a small code sample of a custom widget:

`widgets.py`:

```
from django.forms.widgets import Widget
from django.template import loader
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class MyWidget(Widget):
    template_name = 'myapp/my_widget.html'

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        return {'widget': {
            'name': name,
            'value': value,
        }}

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
        template = loader.get_template(self.template_name).render(context)
        return mark_safe(template)
```

`my_widget.html`:

```
<textarea id="mywidget-{{ widget.name }}" name="{{ widget.name }}">
{% if widget.value %}{{ widget.value }}{% endif %}</textarea>
```

#### Django 1.11

Widgets are now rendered using the [form rendering API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/renderers/).

Comment: Note that widgets' HTML MUST have a name attribute, or else the Django admin will not be able to read their values, and they will just be silently excluded from the form submission.

Comment: It would be useful if you gave an example of how to render widgets for Django 1.11+

Answer (score 7):

NOTE: There are three questions here. For the first two questions, see the fuller answer by AndiDog. I'm only answering the third question here:

Q. What widget method is responsible for going from the user's input back to the data model?

A. The `value_from_datadict` method -- it's sort of the inverse of a widget's `render` method. This method is presumably what the Django docs on widgets are referring to when it says "The widget handles the rendering of the HTML, and the extraction of data from a GET/POST dictionary that corresponds to the widget." There's nothing further on this point in the docs, but you can see how it works from the code for the built-in widgets.

Answer (score 3):

Usually I start by inheriting from one of the existing widgets, add a new desired property and then modify a render method. Here's an example for a filterable select widget I implemented. The filtering is done via jquery mobile.

```
class FilterableSelectWidget(forms.Select):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=()):
        super(FilterableSelectWidget, self).__init__(attrs, choices)
        # choices can be any iterable, but we may need to render this widget
        # multiple times. Thus, collapse it into a list so it can be consumed
        # more than once.
        self._data_filter = {}

    @property
    def data_filter(self):
        return self._data_filter

    @data_filter.setter
    def data_filter(self, attr_dict):
        self._data_filter.update(attr_dict)

    def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):
        option_value = force_text(option_value)
        if option_value in selected_choices:
            selected_html = mark_safe(' selected="selected"')
            if not self.allow_multiple_selected:
                # Only allow for a single selection.
                selected_choices.remove(option_value)
        else:
            selected_html = ''
        # use self.data_filter
        filtertext = self.data_filter.get(option_value)
        data_filtertext = 'data-filtertext="{filtertext}"'.\
            format(filtertext=filtertext) if filtertext else ''
        return format_html('<option value="{0}"{1} {3}>{2}</option>',
                           option_value,
                           selected_html,
                           force_text(option_label),
                           mark_safe(data_filtertext))
```

Then in the views where I create a form, I'll set the data_filter for the field.

```
        some_form.fields["some_field"] = \
            forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices,
                              widget=FilterableSelectWidget)
        some_form.fields["some_field"].widget.data_filter = \
            data_filter
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on Django's site doesn't help with this at all. It's suggestions on [customisation of widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-), break the use of `form.as_p()` which then jeopardises the value of forms as presented in Django, i.e.,: an assemblage of widgets.

The solutions I liked best is [floppyforms](https://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It facilitates the definition of widgets using templates and is a (almost) transparent replacement for Django's own forms module. It has excellent documentation and is easy to pick up.