# Django - Time range widget

Tags: django, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider, django-widget

I'd like to use [jQueryUI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range-vertical) as a widget allowing to configure business hours.

So I did this models:

```
WEEKDAYS = [
  (1, _("Monday")),
  (2, _("Tuesday")),
  (3, _("Wednesday")),
  (4, _("Thursday")),
  (5, _("Friday")),
  (6, _("Saturday")),
  (7, _("Sunday")),
]

class OpeningHours(models.Model)
    comp = models.ForeignKey('Company')
    weekday = models.IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS, unique=True)
    from_hour = models.TimeField()
    to_hour = models.TimeField()

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to='company_logos')
```

I know the markup to do the controllers such as:

```
<div class="slider-block">
    <div class="slider-end">18:00</div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="slider-start">08:00</div>
    <div class="slider-day">Tue</div>
</div>
```

Which gives something similar (with some additionnal css/js)

[image]

But I'm unable to implement it as a form widget

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707192/django-how-to-build-a-custom-form-widget

Comment: The slider isn't tied to a form input, so you'll have to add callbacks to the slider `stop` event and populate some hidden inputs accordingly  so that a form can post this data. To render such a thing and the scripting required for it, you'll need to make a custom form widget and override its `render` method to add this extra DIV, hidden input, and script markup

Comment: It would be much easier to make this a one off- and hard code all of this. All you need is your form field values as hidden inputs which would need to be populated by the values in this slider widget whenever it changes.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't thought about hidden inputs populated with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @YujiTomita for comments and here is my solution:

The basic idea is to generate a formset with hidden inputs, one of which is calling some css/javascript.
And javascript will populate the values.

**widget**

```
class OpeningHoursWidget(forms.HiddenInput):
    class Media:
        js = (
            'https://ajax.googleapis.com/[...]jquery-ui.min.js',
            'js/business_hours.js',
        )
        css = {'all': (
            'https://ajax.googleapis.com/[...]jquery-ui.custom.css',
            'css/business_hours.css',
        )}
```

**form**

```
class UserOpeningHoursForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OpeningHours
        fields = ('weekday', 'from_hour', 'to_hour')
        widgets = {
            'weekday': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'class': 'hours-weekday'}),
            'from_hour': OpeningHoursWidget(attrs={'class': 'hours-start'}),
            'to_hour': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'class': 'hours-end'}),
        }
```

**view**

```
UserOpeningHoursFormSet = formset_factory(UserOpeningHoursForm, extra=0)
obj['formset'] = UserOpeningHoursFormSet(initial=hours)
```

**template**

```
    <div id="slider-block-hidden">
        <div class="slider-end"></div>
        <div class="slider"></div>
        <div class="slider-start"></div>
        <div class="slider-day"></div>
    </div>
{{ formset.media }}
{% for hours in formset %}
    <div class="slider-block">
    {{ hours }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**javascript** (with jquery)

```
$(function() {
    days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    $('.slider-block').each(function () {
        start = $(this).find('.hours-start').val();
        end = $(this).find('.hours-end').val();
        day_id = $(this).find('.hours-weekday').val();
        hidden_slider = $('#slider-block-hidden').clone();
        $(this).append(hidden_slider.find('.slider-end').text(end));
        $(this).append((slider = hidden_slider.find('.slider')));
        $(this).append(hidden_slider.find('.slider-start').text(start));
        $(this).append(hidden_slider.find('.slider-day').text(days[day_id]));
        slider.slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 1440,
            step: 15,
            values: [ ttm(start), ttm(end) ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).siblings('.slider-start').text(mtt(ui.values[0]));
                $(this).siblings('.slider-end').text(mtt(ui.values[1]));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

`ttm()` and `mtt()` are functions for minutes-time conversions/formatting

**css**

```
#slider-block-hidden {
    display: none;
}

.slider-block {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}

.slider {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Maybe there would be a way to subclass widget's render to avoid much javascript.