# How create custom tree widget for ModelMultipleChoiceField in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-widget, django-1.10

In my form I have `function` field which is `ModelMultipleChoiceField` where I want to add selected by user functions. As `queryset` function field take all objects of `Group`. Can someone help me to create custom widget as the picture below for that field? Also here below you can see html of my widget (`tree_widget.html`).

[image]

**tree_widget.html:**

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <p>{{ group }}</p>
    {% for task in group.task_set.all %}
        <p>{{ task }}</p>
        {% for function in task.function_set.all %}
            <p>
               <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="{{ function }}">{{ function }}
            </p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**forms.py:**

```
class RequirementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    function = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=True, widget=CustomTreeWidget, queryset=Group.objects.none())

    class Meta:
        model = Requirement
        fields = ('function',)

    def __init__(self, all_groups, all_user_characteristics, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequirementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['function'].queryset = all_groups  # I take all Group objects from view
```

**widgets.py:**

```
class CustomTreeWidget(CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    template_name = 'tree_widget.html'
    ???
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: How to build a custom form widget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707192/django-how-to-build-a-custom-form-widget)

Comment: @JohnMoutafis Its two different questions. Maybe only titles are the same but problems are different. If you want I can change the title.

Comment: it is not a matter of titles, but of context. If you follow the solutions given in the above-linked post, you will be able to construct a solution for your problem.

Comment: No one of this answers didnt describes my problem. No one use ModelMultipleChoiceField with treeview. Do you have any other ideas my fried?