# django widget.type is incorrect in custom widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-widget

I'm new to django. I'm going to use a custom widget for the check box. Here is my form.py:

```
class SupervisorForm(forms.Form):
    is_manager = forms.BooleanField(label=_("manager"),  required=False)
```

I searched through whole project and realized that this forms is rendered from this file: (forms/widgets/input.html) 
the code is:

```
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}"{% if widget.value != None %} value="{{ widget.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% endif %}{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %} />
```

now I have created a custom widget called SwitchWidgetCheckboxInput

```
class SwitchWidgetCheckboxInput(ClearableFileInput):
    template_name = 'utils/SwitchWidgetCheckboxInput.html'

    @property
    def media(self):
        js = ("utils/switch_widget_checkbox_input/SwitchWidgetCheckboxInput.js",)
        css = {'all': ("utils/switch_widget_checkbox_input/SwitchWidgetCheckboxInput.css",)}
        return forms.Media(js=js, css=css)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        """
        Returns this Widget rendered as HTML, as a Unicode string.
        """
        context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
        return self._render(self.template_name, context, renderer)
```

my js and css are blank at the moment.
and changed the form.py in this way:

```
class SupervisorForm(forms.Form):
is_manager = forms.BooleanField(label=_("manager"), required=False, widget=SwitchWidgetCheckboxInput)
```

and copied the same input.html content to my widget html but surprisingly the checkbox turned into a file input! I used a breakpoint in my widget html and realized that widget.type is file, while i used breakpoint in input.html before applying my custom widet the widget.type was checkbox.

another point is that in my widget html I changed

```
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}"{% if widget.value != None %} value="{{ widget.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% endif %}{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %} />
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ widget.name }}"{% if widget.value != None %} value="{{ widget.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% endif %}{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %} />
```

but that's not working(when i check it and save the formset it is not saved checked).
what is happening exactly?

Comment: Is there is a particular reason your `SwitchWidgetCheckboxInput ` inherits from `ClearableFileInput ` ?...

Comment: @ClémentDenoix actually not, I do not know what to inherit from..can that be the cause? and shall I replace it?

Comment: In your question, you say `...but surprisingly the checkbox turned into a file input`. You widget inherit from `ClearableFileInput` who is, as the name show, a file input widget...

Comment: @ClémentDenoix oh you are right..what should be the base class so?

Comment: Did you read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567258/6935780 ? Found by typing in Google "Django build custom widget"...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: How to build a custom form widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707192/django-how-to-build-a-custom-form-widget)