# Django - Remove currently displayed image link In An Image Edit Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using Django 2.2 for a project, I want to remove the currently displayed image link from the user update form as shown in the image below, how do I do this?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IHtI.png)

```
forms.py


from .models import Profile



class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
        
        
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
        help_texts = {
            'username': None,
        }

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['profile_pic']
```

Comment: You are using the preconfigured `UserCreationForm`, which makes it much harder to customize. In general, I avoid Django Forms for that exact reason; they are too far built into the system, which makes them harder to customize.

Comment: I agree with Nat.  You could also create a new widget and specify that new widget for profile_pic as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707192/django-how-to-build-a-custom-form-widget

Comment: did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change ImageField to FileInput using widgets. I use Django version 4.1.1 and it works for me.

```
# forms.py

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    profile_pic = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput)

    class Meta:
    ...
```

[image]