# Django use of form input without calling form

Tags: django, django-forms

it might be dumb question, but is it okey to use input without calling form.

**my form**

```
class st_image(forms.ModelForm):
    pro_img =forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={"id" :"upload_image", "class":"form-control image"}))
    
    class Meta:
        model=CustomUser
        fields= [ 'pro_img']
```

**my View**

```
def st_profile_img(request):
    pk = request.user.id
    obj = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, pk=pk)
    form=st_image(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None, instance=obj)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if(form.is_valid()):       
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Амжилттай бүртгэлээ")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('st_profile'))
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Зөвхөн зураг хийнэ үү")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('st_profile'))
```

**My template**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'st_profile_img' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                            id="image-form">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <label for="upload_image" class="text-center student-profile-img">
                                <img id="uploaded_image" class="image-responsive" src="{{ user.pro_img.url }}" alt="">
                                <div class="overlay">
                                    <div class="text">Засах</div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="file" name="pro_img" class="image" id="upload_image"
                                    oninput="uploadImage()" style="display: none;" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg" />
                            </label>
                        </form>
```

as you can see i didn't use {{form}} so is it okay use input like this(with using same name with expected form input)?

Or is there any correct way to call input name using **form**? (other than request.POST.get and not using attrs)

Comment: it is ok to put the fields manually and there is no problem with that, your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you don't need to use `{{ form }}` in your template in order for the form to work. You will, however, need to supply all the correct `<input>` tags:

```
<input type="file" name="pro_img" ...>
```

This would have been done automatically if you rendered it like this:

```
{{ form.pro_img }}
```

But in that case you wouldn't be able to customize the `<input>` tags, which is probably why you have chosen the first approach.

Another way to customize your input fields is by [creating your own custom widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707192/django-how-to-build-a-custom-form-widget), but this is probably a bit more work and not really needed in your case.